# gdb - no debugging symbols found - but debugger works anyway

Tags: debugging, gdb, debug-symbols, intel-fortran, icc

I thought that in order to make debugging possible with gdb, it needed to find the debugging symbols, but gdb apparently just works without them (?).
I am mixing c code and fortran code. Today my goal was to debug the c portion of the code. The main is in c and the fortran code intervenes only in some library that are called by this main. 
I compile that bit of the code I am interested in with icc on linux with the following flags:

```
-g -debug full
```

When I run gdb on the code it says

'Reading symbols from /my/path/myexecutable.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.'

but then I succeed in debugging my c-code correctly. It reads the code lines and step correctly, etc. 
I am very happy that everything works, but my question is: should gdb show that statement about not finding debugging symbols? or maybe they are not needed??

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the error message is not so much wrong as incomplete, and should more accurately report that SOME debugging symbols were not found.  They are DEFINITELY needed to connect the binary to the source.